# Tracking down S3 Costs (S3FS)

Tags: amazon-s3, s3fs

During a transition, our S3 costs jumped a lot due to ListBucket and HeadObject calls.  We are trying to figure out how to debug a sudden increase in our S3 costs. We made some changes that should NOT have affected it but the major change seems to be

- 10-20X increase in HeadObject calls
- Sudden appearance of ListBucket calls

[image]

I have attached a chart showing the jump between the April 10, 2018 and April 14, 2018. The dates in between, we made the following changes

- Changed from (debian 8) S3FS v1.61 (super old from 2012, not even in Github) to v1.84 (latest)

  - https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse
- Moved from N. Virginia to N. California AZ (10% higher cost)
- The giant yellow bars are showing the moving of the files using Amazon CLI (April 11 to 13)
- In order to try to calm this down, we added to the mount command in /etc/fstab the following: 
  `noatime,stat_cache_expire=3600,enable_noobj_cache`
- The bars that look uneven starting Apr 14 are now stable around $25/day

Options that are already there were there since the start (no change)
`_netdev,allow_other,use_cache=/tmp,umask=0000,use_path_request_style,ensure_diskfree=10240`

We have done the following to try to debug this

- Enabled S3 Logging
- Dumped the logs into Athena and then CSV export into MySQL
- These logs are just 1 days worth
- Screenshot "query 1" shows that there is 4.8m hits into a path ... basically, we think it is traversing the entire directory tree (with most like about 100k files) looking for a file if it exists
  Screenshot "query 2" shows the same thing (kind of) where it is also doing down a path

[image]

[image]

Not really sure what else to do but our normal bill of about $5/day (including other services) is now about $25/day (5x increase) .. with the /etc/fstab changes, it is down to $13/day but still trying to get it to $5/day if we can get back to the zero ListBucket calls and 20% of the HeadObject calls.

Any ideas on what to try greatly appreciated.

Comment: probably want to try https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/blob/c5af62b023cd38077406c7cbc6eb682a6d069ca1/src/s3fs.cpp#L4627 as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ListBucket and HeadObject API calls were being made `updatedb` (and `located`).

Solution:  Add your mount point (in my case /mnt/s3fs) to PRUNEPATHS in `/etc/updatedb.conf` so `updatedb` does not include this when it scans

- https://linux.die.net/man/5/updatedb.conf
- https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/issues/193#issuecomment-109617253

Comment: Thanks @ChrisGo for the question and your follow-up answer!  
What diagnostics or clues led you to "updatedb" as the culprit?

Comment: It was digging into the API calls being made (chart above) -- this shows that the files are not getting pulled down but it was something that was getting the metadata (Head and ListBucket).  Then we were able to isolate that these calls are being made in "bursts" approx 1x/day so that made us think it was some type of indexing happening 1x/day by something.  This was in Debian 8 ... Debian 9 does not seem to have updatedb and located